Quarkus OIDC end local session automaticlly
I am using Quarkus 3.14 with Angular as the SPA and Keycloak for authentication.
**I want to implement a feature that forces the user to log in again after a specific time period (e.g., 2 hours) by ending the session locally. **
However, I have two separate applications in the same realm, each with its own client in Keycloak. Therefore, I only want to log the user out of one application while keeping them logged in to the other, without making any changes to the Keycloak configuration.
With my current configuartion I can log in and get two q_session_chuns, when i delete cookies i am still loged in (because of redirect that happens)

quarkus.oidc.enabled=true
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=${oidc.basepath}/realms/test
quarkus.oidc.client-id=some-client
quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=${SECRET}
quarkus.oidc.tls.verification=required
quarkus.oidc.application-type=web-app
quarkus.oidc.grant.type=authorization_code

# What i tryed:
quarkus.oidc.token.refresh-expired=false
quarkus.oidc.authentication.internal-id-token-lifespan=
quarkus.oidc.authentication.session-age-extension=


but nothing worked for me :/

Hi, the grant.type property there is in the quarkus.oidc-client namespace, refresh-expired is false by default, internal-id-token is for OAuth2 cases, and session-age-extension is about facilitating a correct session extension. Please check https://quarkus.io/guides/security-oidc-code-flow-authentication#logout-and-expiration ? I think you can have a local logout method which can clear the session cookie, SPA can ping this method after 2 hours. Or you can try to experiment with the back-channel or even front-channel logout configured for the specific KC client
